# Set scroll start position in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-hooks

I want to make scroll only in chosen place.Before that it have to be impossible scroll the website.

```
    const [doStart] = useState({
        startScroll: false
      });
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        
        const onScroll = () => {
          const scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

          if ( scrollPos === 1000) {
            doStart(state => ({ ...state, startScroll: true,  }));
          }
        };
    
        window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      }, [])
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have tried and what you are looking for?

Comment: Sure thing, to kick things off can you provide a full working example of what you have so far?